# Incorrect alignment between two TikZ nodes' boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I'd like to mimic an Italian referendum sheet with two rectangular boxes containing “Sì” and “No”. I wrote the following code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[margin = 0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[anchor = base] node [%
        minimum size = 1.5cm, draw, inner sep = 2.5pt, fill = white, %
        thick, scale = 2] at (5,4) {\Huge \textsc{Sì}} %
        node [minimum size = 1.5cm, draw, inner sep = 2.5pt, fill = white, %
        thick, scale = 2] at (15,4) {\Huge \textsc{No}};
    
        \draw[red, ultra thick] (3,4) -- (18,4) (3,5.3) -- (18,5.3) %
        (3,6) -- (18,6) (3,3) -- (18,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is like the following:
[image: Incorrect alignment]

As the red lines suggest, while the words are aligned, the “boxes” around them aren’t. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up `text height` and `text depth`:

```
\documentclass[margin = 0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[anchor = base] node [%
    minimum size = 1.5cm, text height=2em, text depth=.15em, draw, inner sep = 2.5pt, fill = white, %
    thick, scale = 2] at (5,4) {\Huge \textsc{Sì}} %
    node [minimum size = 1.5cm, text height=2em, text depth=.15em, draw, inner sep = 2.5pt, fill = white, %
    thick, scale = 2] at (15,4) {\Huge \textsc{No}};
    
    \draw[red, ultra thick] (3,4) -- (18,4) (3,5.3) -- (18,5.3) %
    (3,6) -- (18,6) (3,3) -- (18,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]